# Spring oauth2 - difference between authorization service and globalUserDetails

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I try to understand idea of oauth2. I learn from this tutorial:
http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/

I would understand what is the main difference between

```
@Autowired
public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("ADMIN").and()
    .withUser("bob").password("abc123").roles("USER");
}
```

from class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration

and

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

    clients.inMemory()
        .withClient("my-trusted-client")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
        .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
        .secret("secret")
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120).//Access token is only valid for 2 minutes.
        refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);//Refresh token is only valid for 10 minutes.
}
```

from class AuthorizationServerConfiguration.

I understand that the first case touches simple users of my application.
And the second case touches authorization of my app? What is difference between credentials:

bill abc123 and my-trusted-client secret?

I can't catch the convention and I will be very grateful for explanation of it ;) Is my-trusted-client login of the application and bill login of her user? The token is generating for application, not for the user?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2SecurityConfiguration is used for web login, usually this should read form your database;

AuthorizationServerConfiguration is used for oauth client configuration, this info will be set in basic auth header.

Answer (score 0):

There are three parties involved in your authentication ,

1. Say you built OAuth Server like  Facebook
2. You create an App that can authorize against your OAuth Server , say Shopping List App
3. User who would access the Shopping List App

When you configure your OAuth Server , it should be able to authorize your user as well as your shopping list app

You use below to configure how OAuth server would authorize a client,

```
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

    clients.inMemory()
        .withClient("my-trusted-client")

...
}
```

Once your app verify itself using above credentials , OAuth server will ask user to verify itself by issuing a login page(say for ex Facebook login).

You will enter your credentials but the OAuth server needs to verify them before issuing the authorization code , those credentials is what you are configuring in,

```
public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("ADMIN").and()
    .withUser("bob").password("abc123").roles("USER");
}
```